# Multi-site: Change the URL of main site to HTTPS

Tags: multisite

I've setup the multisite on a fresh installation of WordPress.

Then I created some other websites, so, in the end, I have something like this

- http://example.com
- http://site1.example.com
- http://site2.example.com
- http://site3.example.com

I have then installed an SSL digital certificate, so I changed the URLs of the websites to match the HTTPS scheme:

- http://example.com
- 
- 
- 

To change the scheme I gone to `Sites > All Sites`, then clicked on each site and in tab "Information" (the first one) I simply changed the scheme and saved.

This worked.

**The only site left without the `https` is http://example.com: for this, in fact, I have cannot change the URL.**

If I go to `Sites > All Sites` and click on it, in fact, in the first tab "Information" the URL is not editable and is in the form http://example.com, without the https scheme.

How can I change it?

I'd like to change it now, before I start to install plugins and write articles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest editing the `wp-config.php` file, and adding:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');
```

**However for multisite** [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite) it says you should edit `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` and `PATH_CURRENT_SITE`, if there is such thing defined in a multisite wp-config.

First suggestion is based on this [article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Answer (score 5):

I would just:

1. Comment out the multisite code in wp-config.php
2. Login again to WP
3. Go back to settings and reading as if a single site.
4. change http to https
5. uncomment multisite code in wp-config.php
6. Proceed as normal

Done

Comment: Thanks a million. This was a live saver... . You might change wp-content to wp-config... .

Answer (score 1):

It seems some updates to WP core have improved things.
I had a warning in Site Health, saying that the site wasn't configured to use HTTPS.
'Click here to fix it' it said. So I did, and now the site uses https.
Your mileage may vary but it's by far the easiest thing to try first.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me!

In fact, I just had to temporarily change:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
```

to

```
define('MULTISITE', false);
```

Comment: Is that Jesus's answer or D.Dan's answer that you're agreeing with? (I think Jesus was effectively suggesting the same thing by commenting out the MULTISITE define.)